# how implement reverse timer inside parent window for a popup window?

Tags: javascript, popup, window

i have a popup window like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('http://www.MyPoPUp.com', '_blank', 'location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no');
</script>
```

how can i implement reverse timer in Parent Window Related To That PoPUp Window?
(i want to lock parent with a reverse timer inside for showing a popup window to my users!
and after ending of that timer unlock parent.if user close the PoPUp Window during timer, 
show a message in parent window to that user)

thanks for attention and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

> http://forums.asp.net/t/1291427.aspx

or this one

> http://programmerramblings.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-session-timeout-control-jquery.html

Comment: thanks for answer / but i am looking for a way to make a relation between that popup window and countdown timer and this is why i asked this Q! those links tell us about countdown timer only! but what about relation between countdown timer and popup window (google does not help about this issue)?